# Get the source file name of hyperlink in php

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I have a code in php which is being called from many web pages. Now I want to know the .php name from where hyperlink is being clicked.

Example:

file1.php

```
<a href="file2.php?id=2">Click this link</a>
```

now on clicking "Click this link" file2.php will open.
I want to determing the file1.php name when control is passed to file2.php.

Comment: `if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { 
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Look at the referrer: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` if set OR
2. add javaScript:

--

```
<a href="file2.php?id=2" onClick="location=this.href+'&ref='+escape(location.href)">Click this link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

$_SERVER is a PHP super global variable which holds information about headers, paths, and script locations.

echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

> Returns the complete URL of the current page (not reliable because not
>   all user-agents support it)

Answer (score 1):

Inside file2.php, do this:

```
<?php
 $referrer_file = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
 echo $referrer_file;
?>
```